# How to show isomorphism between extension fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Can anyone help me to show isomorphism between $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p})$ and $\mathbb Q(-\sqrt{q})$. where $p$ and $q$ are two distinct prime numbers.
As i am check the property of isomorphism but I don't no how to prove it.

Please help, thank you

Comment: (-q)^1/2 instead of -q^1/2

Answer (score 2):

The two fields are *not* isomorphic because $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ contains a solution to $x^2-p=0$ whereas $\Bbb{Q}(-\sqrt{q})$ does not. This is easily verified by assuming towards a contradiction that there exist $a,b\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that
$$p=(a+b\sqrt{q})^2.$$
Expanding the square quickly shows that no such $a,b\in\Bbb{Q}$ exist.